# Android - programmatically transition background gradient?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I've got two gradient drawable files (an example of one of them):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape>
      <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#DBDBDB"
        android:endColor="#F0F0F0"
        android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

I've got a transition drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_c" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_e" />
  </transition>
```

I want to programmatically fade the activity's background from `gradient_c` to `gradient_e` (and reverse, etc). I'm using this code:
`RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlRAM);
TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) rl.getBackground();
// TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground();
transition.startTransition(500);`

However, when I try to run the code I get an error:
`08-02 12:04:32.223: E/AndroidRuntime(12646): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blogspot.appsversatile.performancer/com.example.app.RAM}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable`

I just want to fade the activity's background to another gradient (from a drawable file). How can I achieve this?

---

---

I've accepted the answer below because he gave me the answer, but the post didn't exactly explain it.
The way I went around this was buy applying my RelativeLayout background to the transition drawable:
`android:background="@drawable/transition`.

I then just used:
`RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlRAM);
TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) rl.getBackground();
transition.startTransition(500);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The StackTrace is explaining that you are trying to cast a StateListDrawabl to a TransitionDrawable. This can't be done.

```
(TransitionDrawable) rl.getBackground();
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable
```

You're using a StateListDrawable, so you should use something like:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlRAM);
StateListDrawable drawable = (StateListDrawable) rl.getBackground();
TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) drawable.getCurrent();
transition.startTransition(500);
```

Comment: What does the `getCurrent();` method do? Also - tried this, another error: `08-02 12:43:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(14720): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable`. How do I cast it properly?

Comment: I think you did not applied the right drawable to your RelativeLayout. Can you describe your RelativeLayout definition ?   `getCurrent()` returns he current drawable that will be used by this drawable. For simple drawables, this is just the drawable itself. For drawables that change state like StateListDrawable and LevelListDrawable this will be the child drawable currently in use.

Comment: I've got a RL as the main layout with a gradient background `android:background="@drawable/gradient_c"`.

Comment: You should use the transitionDrawable instead. (the second sample of code)

Comment: I changed it to `android:background="@drawable/transition` and it still comes up with the same error as before stating I cannot cast TransitionDrawable to StateListDrawable. If you know a working example would you mind posting it?

Comment: Now tht you've define your RelativeLayout with a drawable of type TransitionDrawable, you can directly cast it to a TransiationDrawable. TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) rl.getBackground();